# How can i make python maximize 3.7 issues

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
import os
import msvcrt
import subprocess
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

SW_MAXIMIZE = 3

kernel32.GetConsoleWindow.restype = wintypes.HWND
kernel32.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize.restype = wintypes._COORD
kernel32.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE,)
user32.ShowWindow.argtypes = (wintypes.HWND, ctypes.c_int)


def maximize_console(lines=None):
    fd = os.open('CONOUT$', os.O_RDWR)
    try:
        hCon = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(fd)
        max_size = kernel32.GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(hCon)
        if max_size.X == 0 and max_size.Y == 0:
            raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    finally:
        os.close(fd)
    cols = max_size.X
    hWnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
    if cols and hWnd:
        if lines is None:
            lines = max_size.Y
        else:
            lines = max(min(lines, 9999), max_size.Y)
        subprocess.check_call('mode.com con cols={} lines={}'.format(
                                cols, lines))
        user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

this used to work in 3.5....
Since the new update its not working....
I just want to maximize...not fullscreen...
It says that it doesnt recognize ctypes
Please help.

```
$ python Jo_Crypt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Jo_Crypt.py", line 6, in <module>
    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
NameError: name 'ctypes' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually import `ctypes`, `from ctypes import wintypes` means you imported `wintypes` from it.

Use `import ctypes`

Comment: dude!!!! thanks...... that was it....Thanks a lot...I have to turn up my project tomorrow...Thanks a ton